# Azure API App service hosting wcf service

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-api-apps

I have created a wcf service and self hosted it. I want to push it over the azure cloud as API APP service and not a cloud service? Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

I actually something similar: hosting REST endpoints and a WCF endpoint in an Azure deployed API App
There was nothing special to consider. Just created the WCF within my solution, configured `basicHttpBinding` correctly to work with `https`.

Let me know where exactly you're struggling.

Comment: Got that, Now I am publishing all my WCF service as App Service , working fine. Thanks